# Javascript number resets to 0 if bits are shifted too much

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

So I was trying to make some functions in javascript that shift and manipulate the bits of numbers. However, I found the following behavior in my console

```
> var a = 1;
undefined
> a <<= 3
8
> a <<= 55
67108864
> a <<= 40
0
```

My question is, if the value gets larger above a certain point, why does the number go back to zero? In other languages like python the number just keeps getting larger, or a notation is used to hold the value of the number. Or, an overflow error is shown. Why does JavaScript simply reset the number to zero?

Comment: Because bitwise operators and shift operators operate on 32-bit ints.

Comment: But aren't all javascript numbers floating point numbers internally? That's why i am confused here

Comment: @JoshWeinstein Not when performing bitwise operations, in that case they're treated as 32-bit integers

Comment: See the spec: [12.8.3.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) they are run through `ToInt32()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift):

> Shift operators convert their operands to 32-bit integers in big-endian order and return a result of the same type as the left operand. The right operand should be less than 32, but if not only the low five bits will be used.

So in the case of your `55 (0x110111)` and `40 (0x101000)` you are bit-shifting by `23 (0x10111)` and `8 (0x01000)` respectively:

```
> var a = 1;
undefined
> a <<= 3
8
> a <<= 23
67108864
> a <<= 8
0
```

Note that although these aren't the same as what you wrote, the answers are the same as for why you get 0, consider the bits:

```
> var a = 1;
undefined
> a <<= 3 + 23
67108864    // 0x000[00000100000000000000000000000000]
> a <<= 8
0           // 0x100[00000000000000000000000000000000]
```

The square brackets denote what value is actually used to determine the value of the number, the section to the left is discarded. As you can see you've bitshifted the 1 all the way off the left of the number resulting in 0 being left over.

Note the below snippet, after reaching the 32 shift mark all results are 0:

```js
var a = 1;
for(var i = 1; i < 40; i++){
    a <<= 1;
    console.log(i, a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The semantics of a left bit shift are defined in [ES2018 section 12.9.3.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-left-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation). The main thing to understand is that the left operand is is cast to a 32-bit signed integer, and the result is also a 32-bit integer.

In a left bit shift the left operand is shifted the number of bit positions specified by the (lowest 5 bits of) the right operand.

For, for example, `1 << 3` is, performs the binary transformation

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

to

```
00000000000000000000000000001000
```

which is `8`.

The operation `67108864 << 40` (which is the same as the operation `67108864 << 8`) is operating on the 32-bit number

```
00000100000000000000000000000000
```

When you shift this up eight bits, you end up with

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which is 35 bits. Since the output of a bit-shift is always a signed 32-bit number, it loses its top thee bits, resulting in the lower 32 bit expressing `0`.